# Expression tree differences between C# and VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, expression-trees

I have a library working on expression trees. The library need to work with both C# and VB.Net

Noticed some differences between the languages on how the expression trees are constructed

- String comparison
  `() => "a" == "b"` becomes `Expression.Equals("a", "b")`
  `Function() "a" = "b"` becomes `Expression.Equals(Expression.Call(CompareString, "a", "b"), 0)`
  (I understand why VB.Net uses CompareString here)
- String concatenation
  `() => "a" + "b"` becomes `Expression.Add("a", "b", String.Concat)`
  `Function() "a" & "b"` becomes `Expression.Call(String.Concat, "a", "b")`
- Optimization?
  `() => !(1 == 2)` becomes `Expression.Not(Expression.Equals(1, 2))`
  `Function() Not (1 = 2)` becomes `Expression.NotEqual(1, 2)`

My library handle all these differences but **are there more differences I need to look out for?**

**Edit**
Some explanation of what my code does.

The system I work with has a filter for documents that you specify like this:

```
var filter = document.Filter;
filter.LeftParanthesis();
filter.Column(columnNumber);
filter.Equals();
filter.Value("abc");
filter.RightParanthesis();
filter.And();
filter.LeftParanthesis();
...
document.Refresh();
```

To make it easier to use the filter my code allows you to specify the filter as a `Expression<Func<bool>>` lambda.

```
Expression<Func<bool>> filter = () => (123.AsStringColumn() == "abc") && (...);
filter.Apply(document);
```

My code then iterates the expression tree and calls the document filter methods as specified above.
The filter does not have support for everything you can put into a lambda. Method calls is the most obvious one.

Since VB.Net generates method calls in some cases where C# does not I need to intercept these and handle them differently.

Comment: captured-variables, anonymous-types, and opaque-identifiers (`let`) probably need some love; I suspect this is open-ended, though

Comment: @Marc The naming is probably different but do you expect the tree to look different as well?

Comment: Look out for implicit conversions with `option strict off` in VB.NET. Not really a difference per se since C# doesn't support it, but it might introduce extra calls you might be interested in handling.

Comment: @Julien Thanks for mentioning conversions. Fortunatly I don't need to handle them since the target system does not support conversions and  I already support constant conversions via constant sub-expression evaluation.

Comment: What about non-standard object comparisons (user written comparison routines)?

Comment: @adam Do you have an example where the expression tree for non standard comparisons is different depending on if it is generated in C# or Vb.Net? I mentioned how string comparison differs in the question but have not seen it for other types.

Comment: I do not.  I have seen examples on MSDN. Check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727

Comment: Please remember that from .NET version to .NET version these little differences might get changed.

Comment: Have you seen this? One more difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811868/expression-trees-different-compiler-behaviour-for-actiont-in-c-sharp-and-vb

Comment: @kamil, looked at the link and did some tests. The difference is what operations VB.Net allows in expressions. The extra operations allowed does not make sense in my context so it is ok to get an error message. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but what exactly are you doing with these expression trees. My understanding is that if you were building these trees manually, either approach would be valid, in either language - ie the results would be the same. What, specifically, is the problem that arises from these differences?

Comment: @guysherman, I work with an ERP system where you build filters using methods like `.ColumnEqual(columnName, value)` etc. My code convert an expression tree to the ERP methods similar to how Linq2Sql converts to a WHERE clause.

Comment: We use a C# library that generates and mutates expression trees and is used heavily by VB users as well as C# users.  We have NO special code to handle any differences so I'm not sure there is a real issue here.  You don't need to write the lib in both languages, you just need to consume it in both languages.

Comment: "are there more differences I need to look out for? ... The filter does not have support for everything you can put into a lambda" - it seems to me you simply need to enumerate in your test cases all the C# and VB.NET expressions you *do* support, and ensure they are handled by your code. You're happy to say that not everything is supported, so decide what *is* supported, and support it.

Comment: I know that product, and I think you're going to run into other problems. For example, if you have parentheses around a single condition, it tends to display a "SQL Query Error" message to the user.

Comment: @AakashM, that is what I do but getting full coverage for combinations of 20+ nodes with 3 different types in two languages is a lot of work. Richard, it works fine. I use it daily but I only use c#. The rules are not that difficult and using expression trees hides the details from the user.

Comment: This looks similar to my question I asked a few years ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742972/why-do-lambda-expressions-in-vb-differ-from-c

Comment: I know the compilers handles differently c# `"a"=="b"` and vb.net `"a"="b"` boolean expression. So some of the differences might reflect differences in compilers.

Comment: Instead, can you look into Dynamic LINQ? Even if VB generates little different lambda, why dont you just compile and invoke lambda, why do you have to intercept them? You dont need to do anything with lambda if you implement IList or ICollection or IEnumerable properly, Linq will do its job regardless.

Comment: The question by itself is very interesting.. but what you are trying to do is a nightmare from a maintenance point of view. It will change from C# version to the next one, and in the next version of VB as well... Until, with Roslyn or later, the two will converge. But now you will have to retest everything every time

Comment: @AkashKava is right.  You should implement an iteration strategy for the document using the decorator pattern rather than traversing the expression tree yourself.

Comment: @AkashKava, i am not using the expression trees for LINQ.

Comment: @dema80, i don't think the implementation of the trees will change. Changes would break LINQ, EF and any other IQuryable provider.

Comment: @JoeCoder, can you explain what you mean? I am transforming an expression tree into a sequence of method calls. How can I do that without iterating the tree?

Comment: @adrianm I began to implement an answer, but realized that you aren't really doing functional programming here.  You're just using expression tree traversal to perform code translation.  This is the wrong tool for the job and won't be maintainable as others have mentioned, even if you only implement in one language.

Comment: @joecoder, which tool is wrong? What do you mean with implementing in one language? Don't understand the maintainability issue. There are a lot of iqueryable providers like linq2sql and entity framework using the same technique. They will all break if the c# or vb.net compliers starts generating different expression trees.

Comment: @adrianm ...umm.. why? 
Anyway, that is a good point: find a IQueryable provider that works with both VB.Net and C#, and mimic what it is done there

Comment: @dema80, I have looked at other providers but most seem to not handle vb.net. In Linq2sql I found a few vb specific things explicitly mentioned: string comparison, "like" handling and type conversions.

Comment: Not just between compilers, framework differences itself sometime matter. See this answer for an example and the comments under it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8228144/661933

Comment: How do you see the *what it becomes* part? Please enlighten the unlettered but curious. :-)

I tried this but I get the source code string back:

`Expression<Func<int, int, bool>> predicate = (a, b) => a != b;
    
Console.WriteLine(predicate.ToString());`

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, Use linqpad with `predicate.Dump()`

Answer (score 6):

The `/` division operator works differently in C# and VB. In C# it adapts to the data types used, while VB always converts the operands to floating point values:

`() => 1 / 2` becomes `Expression.Divide(1, 2)`
`Function() 1 / 2` becomes `Expression.Divide(Expression.Convert(1, Double), Expression.Convert(2, Double))`

In VB you would need to use the `\` operator for integer division and `/` for floating point division to get the same as the `/` operator in C#.

Comment: Thanks. I think the best way (for me) to handle it is to mention it in the conversion error message.

Comment: Sorry.  VB's quirks drive me insane -- I mean -- a backwards slash?  Uck!

Answer (score 2):

I had to work with C# and VB.Net frequently related to my project and most of the differences I had seen when VB.Net is in unsafe mode. ie if we make the VB.Net typesafe (Option strict on, option explicite on...option all on) it will work like C#.